# How do I force Visual Studio 2008 to save vcproj files with correct locale?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, locale, vcproj

In my team, some are developing using Swedish locale (albeit with English language) and others are using US-English. I prefer Swedish formatting of date/time/number/currency.

There's a bug in the formatting of the version field in the vcproj file which means that it's constantly being changed from comma to dot and back again, depending on who edited the file last.

The diffs look like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
 <VisualStudioProject
        ProjectType="Visual C++"
-       Version="9.00"
+       Version="9,00"
        Name="TehProject"
        ProjectGUID="{BDFA4CC2-70CA-4B98-AC31-FC233434B56A3}"
```

Any ideas how to resolve this? It's pretty minor, but it starting to get on my nerves. :)

Comment: Not really a problem 10 years later. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing same problem. After investigation it looks to me that in Windows there is no standard way to set locale application-specific. It can be changed system-wide only.

The only solution that can be done by Windows standard tools is to use `runas` command and run VS IDE (`devenv.exe`) under different user account with English locale (or some locale which decimal separator is point). This is ugly solution that suffers from several disadvantages (e.g. you shall enter password manually or use unsecure `/savecred` param, changes to main user account profile shall be manually replicated to 'IDE' account, maybe something else that I've missed). By my opinion it doesn't worth its price.

Answer (score 0):

I found the AppLocal utility which should allow running a specific locale: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13209

Will test someday.